# How to prevent libphonenumber-js from removing dashes when formatting a number?

Tags: libphonenumber

I want to use libphonenumber-js to format a phone number. With the code below it always removes the dash. How can I keep the dash?

```
const phoneNumber = parsePhoneNumber("+494021337342-53")
console.log("phoneNumber: ", phoneNumber, phoneNumber.formatInternational())

// +49 40 2133734253
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no native method available in the library to keep the hyphens, however

You can get the national format of the number i.e.

```
const nationalNumber = parsedPhoneNumber(phoneNumber).formatNational();
```

which will give you the hyphenated number, then replace the round brackets if any and also trim it;

```
let phoneNumber = nationalNumber.replace(/\(|\)/g,'').trim()
```

now replace the remaining space with hyphen,

```
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(' ','-');
```

you can then manually add the countryCode like so,

```
phoneNumber = countryCode + phoneNumber. // you will have to find the country code
```